# Booting an HP computer onto disk

Tags: boot, compact-disc

Simple question:
How do I boot an HP dv7-4053cl into bios where I can boot to a CD instead of the internal HDD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Steps

1. Reboot your laptop.
2. When the HP splash screen appears, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter the *Startup Menu*.
3. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to enter the *Boot Device Options*.
4. Two possible scenarios:

   - Your optical disk drive appears in the list.

     Select it with the arrow keys and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   - Your optical disc drive does not appear in the list.

     1. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to enter the BIOS setup.
     2. Go to **System Configuration → Boot Options** and toggle **CD-ROM Boot** to **Enabled**.
     3. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes and start from the top.

Comment: ah awesome. Didn't know to press esc